# High CPU utlization when using WITH RECURSIVE query in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, cpu-usage

We are building hierarchial query using WITH Recursive CTE option.The query response time is in acceptable level but there is CPU spike and reaches 100 %

Included all possible filter conditions and added the indexes on filter columns

```
explain analyze WITH RECURSIVE childfolders AS (
SELECT f.id,  f.parent_folder_id 
FROM  f,  doc WHERE f.id = doc.id AND f.project_id = 'projxxx'
AND f.parent_folder_id IN ('docf141440')  
UNION ALL 
SELECT f.id,   f.parent_folder_id 
FROM folder f,  doc, childfolders 
WHERE f.parent_folder_id = childfolders.id AND f.is_deleted = FALSE AND f.id = doc.id    ) 
SELECT id, parent_folder_id FROM childfolders ORDER BY id;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=51140.27..51157.70 rows=6975 width=164) (actual time=10520.316..10547.033 rows=377436 loops=1)
   Sort Key: childfolders.id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 41776kB
   CTE childfolders
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.85..50555.48 rows=6975 width=20) (actual time=0.040..7553.675 rows=377436 loops=1)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..121.45 rows=5 width=20) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan using folder_parent_folder_id on  f  (cost=0.42..81.49 rows=9 width=20) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: ((parent_folder_id)::text = 'docf141440'::text)
                       Filter: ((project_id)::text = 'proj2877'::text)
                 ->  Index Only Scan using document_folder_pk on  doc  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (id = (f.id)::text)
                       Heap Fetches: 0
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..5029.45 rows=697 width=20) (actual time=326.462..830.750 rows=41937 loops=9)
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..4499.12 rows=1161 width=20) (actual time=326.452..445.050 rows=41937 loops=9)
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on childfolders childfolders_1  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=82) (actual time=0.000..3.962 rows=41937 loops=9)
                       ->  Index Scan using folder_parent_folder_id on  f_1  (cost=0.42..89.73 rows=23 width=20) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=377436)
                             Index Cond: ((parent_folder_id)::text = (childfolders_1.id)::text)
                             Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                 ->  Index Only Scan using document_folder_pk on  doc_1  (cost=0.42..0.46 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=377435)
                       Index Cond: (id = (f_1.id)::text)
                       Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  CTE Scan on childfolders  (cost=0.00..139.50 rows=6975 width=164) (actual time=0.041..7683.095 rows=377436 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.520 ms
 Execution Time: 10577.198 ms
```

Is there  way to reduce the CPU spike with out affecting query response time

Answer (score 0):

The estimates are off, yo PostgreSQL chooses a nested loop join when a different strategy might have been better.

You could try to calculate statistics, maybe that helps:

```
ANALYZE f_1;
ANALYZE doc_1;
```

Other than that, the only remedy I can thing of is to disable nested loop joins for that query only:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;
SELECT /* your query */;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thx for the resonse.We tried ANALYZE options and didnt went as expected.If i drop the index of f.parent_folder_id column then there are improvement in CPU utilization however got a hit on query response time